# Ionic 3 local notification every few hours

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, notifications

So I want my app to fire notification every 3 hours by users choice when to start this,
there is a Toggle on the HTML that if the user turn it on I want it to pop up dialog that will ask him the first time he eats on the day and then the app will notify him to eat every 3 hours from this hour.
SO I tried to start this and it looks really hard.
so far I got the notification and didn't figure how to fire the notification every 3 hours,
this is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, IonicPage , AlertController , Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-settings',
  templateUrl: 'settings.html'
})
export class Settings {

  mealNotifierToggle : boolean = false ;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams , private plt: Platform,
  private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {
  }

  scheduleNotification(){
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: "Meal Time",
      text: "Time to eat !",
      every: 'minute' 
    });
  }
}
```

There is any good explanations about how to save the 'Toggle' state even when the app is closed and how to fire the notification every 3 hours?
An explanation for the pop up dialog will be sweet but I really want to try and do it by myself for now, If I won't succeed I will edit this question.
Thanks a lot!

Matan

Comment: Use a (ionChange) on your toggle, to set or kill your scheduled notification.

Comment: Actually it isn't whay I mean.. I want the toggle to open me a pop over when its on to ask me when to start the notifications

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) and especially the 'confirm' part.

Comment: Nice! Thank you mate!
There is any chance you know the answer about the notification? and how to save the data given in the AlertController? Modal?

Comment: You're probably looking for the 'trigger' property. More info can be found at https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#triggers